# Docker Buildx - Building multi-platform images much slower than single platform

Tags: docker, image, jenkins, build, buildx

We have been using docker build for our images.

The build takes place using **Jenkins** slave on ec2 amd64.

`docker build .`
The build takes around 5 minutes.

However, now when using `docker buildx --platform linux/amd64, linux/arm64.`
The build takes much longer around 30 minutes.
From what I understood, it's because the node is amd64 and it's using an emulator for building the arm64.

How can we make it **faster**?

We are having npm install command in our dockerfile and some shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run that command from an `arm64` ec2 instance, like [Graviton](https://aws.amazon.com/pm/ec2-graviton/), it will run MUCH faster.  When we build multi-arch images on `arm64` we can build in a matter of minutes, but when doing the same thing on `amd64`, it can take well over half an hour depending on the image.  `arm64` chips seem to be able to handle the multi-arch builds much better than `amd64`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Another option besides running `docker buildx` from a single host, is to build both images on their native architectures quickly, push the resulting containers to the repo and then push the manifest to combine them into a multi-arch container.  For larger builds this may be the way to go instead of waiting forever for a build to finish.

Sample Refs:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-multi-architecture-image.html
- https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/